# Why would soldiers continue using helmets after the Renaissance?

Tags: technology, warfare, technological-development, military, armors

In my world, it is a mix of Renaissance and 17th century style. For soldiers, they wear helmets as part of their uniform and armor. However, even into their version of the 1700s and 1800s, they continue to wear iron helmets for protection. What conditions would allow them to continue wearing metal helmets into their version of the 1700s and 1800s, like before, rather than changing to hats, like in real history?

[image]

[Source: Richard in a Hat Blog](https://richardhat.blogspot.com/2019/09/morion-helmet.html)

For extra notes:

- A zombie virus starts to rise. It does not end civilization, but it is difficult to get rid of, and technology can still progress
- Gun technology also progresses, and does not stay stagnant
- While there are a few breech-loading guns, the majority only use muzzle-loading
- When I say "soldiers", that goes for all of them. I am aware of the cavalry still continuously wearing helmets, but I am also talking about foot soldiers as well. In addition, these helmets are not for decoration or ceremony, but mainly for actual protection
- For battle tactics, it is a mix of medieval warfare, volley gunfire, and elements of modern warfare (with the exception of some technological limits)
- I know that in history, they went back to using helmets, but I am talking about for the 1700s and 1800s. From there, in my world, they continue to use the helmets, not hats

Comment: Worldbuilding is the creation and consistent use of rules for an imaginary world wherein an infinite number of stories can be told. Storybuilding is the devleopment of plot, character/organization choices, and circumstances. This feels like the latter. Please see the [help/on-topic] page for rules discouraging brainstorming. A way to avoid the problem this causes is to [edit] your Q and explain why ignoring the issue isn't a valid answer?

Comment: A worthwhile consideration is this: One VTC reason is "too story-based." That means the issue depends too much on the needs of the story (called [narrative necessity](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7281/40609)). If you already know what that need is, you can tell us what it is and it becomes a condition for selecting a best answer, thereby removing the problem of "too story-based" (and the issues of my previous comment). The difference between worlbuilding and overcoming writer's block is knowing the outcome you need... or not.

Comment: @JBH What makes my question too story based more specifically?

Comment: You're not distinguishing between a non-story-related issue and a story-related issue. In fact, your quesiton is almost 100% story-related because you admit to advances in both metals and weapons - and yet still want a non-ceremonial excuse for iron helmets. A worldbuilding question can have the story entirely removed from the question, and the question still exists. I can't see that possibility here.

Comment: And then there's still the [help/on-topic] problem: "Questions must be specific as well as answerable. If you are looking for discussion, brainstorming, or an overall process rather than specific questions and answers, the Worldbuilding Stack Exchange might not be a good place for your question."

Comment: And as a final point (then I need to retire for the night), the [help/on-topic] also says, " If on the other hand you aren’t sure what a character (be it an individual or organization) should do, that is out of scope for the site." By definition, a government must choose to not use the most efficient solution for its soldiers. You're literally asking us to explain a choice to not use better materials in the face of superior-to-iron weapons. However, as I pointed out, if you explain your story goal (removing the story-based problem), you overcome most of all this.

Comment: @JBH is it good now?

Comment: What types of firearms are your soldiers using? Also are humans fighting humans in conflict? Or is humanity united against your zombies?

Comment: So apparently you're unaware of and don't believe that practically all modern armies still use, wear and issue 'helmets' to their front line troops to this day and expect them to wear them for personal protection? that would seem to be breathtaking ignorance but I see that your current question appears to be the result of some editing to address previous concerns? You might want to give the current question a proof read, the edits may not have left you with a sensible question.

Comment: They did wear helmets back then, so this is a pretty easy question to answer, like "Give me a real irl reason why the egyptians would build giant triangular tombs."

Comment: @Crafter I presume you mean they started wearing metal "hats" like in the picture, rather than metal helmets. Feel free to replace it with better picture if you meant something different.

Comment: @NepeneNep: There was a brief period from about the end of the 18th to the middle of the 19th centuries when only certain specialized units were issued protective helmets. Helmets returned in universal military favor in the second half of the 19th century.

Comment: The man in the picture **is** wearing a helmet. That style of helmet may be *called* an iron hat, but it is helmet; there were many styles of helmets during history.

Comment: Yeah, the appearance of helmets is entirely up to fashion, and so it's a writer choice. It's a steel object that protects the head, it's a helmet.

Comment: Removing the condition that your people have developed firearms and metal beyond simple iron helmets doesn't really solve the problem. One of the reasons metal helmets began to fall out of favor in the 1500s-1700s was the development of muskets, which didn't need to pierce the helmet to stop the soldier (think "church bell," if nothing else). But you've honestly done nothing to change this from an off-topic "help me write my story" question to an on-topic "help me build my world" question. In fact, your edits haven't materially changed the question at all. Please read the [help/on-topic] page.

Answer (score 7):

## They didn't stop wearing helmets irl history

While armor fell out of fashion with the advancement of guns, [metal helmets remained popular throughout since without a head you die.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secrete_(helmet))

[image]

What they looked like is up to you and fashion in your story.

Comment: +1, cuirassiers often wore helmets through 1700s, and then [Dragoon helmet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragoon_helmet) was introduced.

Answer (score 2):

**Zombie Bite Neck**

In Season 8 Episode 13 of The Walking Dead, a zombie bites Herman on the neck. This is the number one move for zombies. Zombie like bite. Zombie bite neck.

Unfortunately Herman was only wearing his Renaissance-style *Morion*. The iconic metal  hat  you see in depictions of pikemen. The hat did not save him.

[image]

This was doubly tragic because, earlier that day, Herman had been bitten by the very same zombie, while wearing his full Corinthian helmet with the extra long neck guards.

As you see the zombie did not stand a chance.

[image]

Thumbs up.

Answer (score 1):

- [Hand grenades](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grenadier) are significant. Perhaps as part of anti-zombie defenses? But also between human troops. Possibly more howitzer shells. More splinters flying around.
- Developments in antisepsis/antibiotics make injuries to the abdominal cavity more survivable. That increases the relative importance of head and brain injuries (i.e. the importance of preventing them).
- Leaders find that raising new troops is not as cheap as it used to be. They cannot offer the [King's shilling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/King%27s_shilling) to a vagrant and get a new soldier. That makes caring for existing ones more important.

Then one early scientist takes a look at injuries, and takes some counter-intuitive leaps like analyzing [survivorship bias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Survivorship_bias). That isn't more complicated than inventing calculus for artillery trajectories.